# Possibility to remove or change the Teams Notification when you request a Team via graph api

Tags: asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

When you request a Team using graph api,you will get a notification (from Service Account )that you where added to this newly created Team.
It will make user confused.
Just wonder if there is a easy way to hide this notification or change it?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Currently you cannot edit the Teams Notification when you request a Team via graph api. You can edit the Teams notification when you send some messages to channel, By using the summary field. Pleases check the summary field property for chat-Message. Please Raise a [User Voice]https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public-preview/category/182881-developer-platform) to edit the Teams Notification when you request a Team via graph api.